# Extract IDs based on same orders not appearing in previous two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say I have a table like this

```
| userID   | order |
| -------- | ----- |
| 1        | apple |
| 2        | pear  |
| 3        | orange|
| 4        | grape |
| 3        | orange|
| 2        | apple |
| 1        | pear  |
```

I wish to only select the userID's of those that have not made any of the same orders based off the previous 2 orders(rows) So in that case it would reflect

```
| userID   | order |
| -------- | ----- |
| 1        | apple |
| 2        | pear  |
| 3        | orange|
| 4        | grape |
| 2        | apple |
| 1        | pear  |
```

where the last userID of 3 isn't selected.
Please let me know how can this be achieve for SQL query

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  How do define "previous 2 orders?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ordering column (and I'm understanding the question correctly), you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(col2) over (order by <ordering col>) as prev_col2,             
             lag(col2, 2) over (order by <ordering col>) as prev2_col2
      from t
     ) t
where (col2 <> prev_col2 or prev_col2 is null) and
      (col2 <> prev2_col2 or prev2_col2 is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you cannot use LAG.
Notice I added an extra row (apple) to include the case it was ordered in the prior order.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE 
        (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), UserID int, DOrder varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES          
            ( 1, 'apple ')
        ,   ( 2, 'pear  ')
        ,   ( 3, 'orange')
        ,   ( 4, 'grape ')
        ,   ( 3, 'orange')
        ,   ( 2, 'apple ')
        ,   ( 2, 'apple ')
        ,   ( 1, 'pear  ')
;

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
EXCEPT
SELECT  T2.*    
FROM    @Table      T1
JOIN    @Table  T2  ON  T2.UserID   =       T1.UserID
                    AND T2.ID       BETWEEN T1.ID+1 AND T1.ID+2
```